# How can i upgrade pip using cmd?

Tags: pip, pycharm, installation

I want to upgrade pip, using cmd. But it doesn't. 
Release was 19.0.3.

[image: enter link description here]

(There was an update on the latest version side like "setuptools" and i wanted to update to 19.3 using cmd but it didn't work and i did it manually.)

Maybe path can be wrong, so i shared paths.

[image: enter link description here]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

pip is just a PyPI package so you can use it to upgrade itself.

pip install --upgrade pip

On Windows:

python -m pip install --upgrade pip

Comment: well, how can i upgrade "setuptools" package ? Now version 40.8.0.

python -m pip install --upgrade setuptools i used this command to upgrade on cmd. But when i checked version on pycharm it didnt change. https://i.hizliresim.com/LvXdRo.png